# Помогите разобраться с условием для if на php

Tags: php, if

Доброго времени суток форумчани. Столкнулся с проблемой, помогите пожалуйста решить.
Вот код:

```
$action = null; //Тип данных по умолчанию
$type = null; //Тип данных по умолчанию
$variation = null; //Тип данных по умолчанию

$action = '$action'; //Тип данных: string, int или null
$type = '$type'; //Тип данных: string, int или null
$variation = 0; //Тип данных: string, int или null

if ($action)
    $action = "action:" . $action;

if ($type and $action)
    $type = "|type:" . $type;
elseif ($type)
    $type = "type:" . $type;

if ($variation and ($type or $action))
    $variation = "|variation:" . $variation;
elseif ($variation)
    $variation = "variation:" . $variation;
```

Вывод: `action:$action|type:$type0` 
Тут теряется слово `|variation`. Но если `$variation` равен `null` или любому значению отличительному от 0, то все Ок.

---

Пробовал в такой вариации:

```
if ($variation and ($type or $action))
    $variation = "|variation:" . $variation;
elseif ($variation)
    $variation = "variation:" . $variation;
elseif ($variation == 0)
    if (($type or $action))
        $variation = "|variation:" . $variation;
    else
        $variation = "variation:" . $variation;
```

Тут же другая проблема, если `$action` и `$type` не равны `null`, а `$variation` равен ему то: `action:$action|type:$type|variation:`. Отображается `|variation:`, но не должен.

Помогите решить проблему. Какое условие необходимо поставить что бы:

1. Что бы указании всех трёх переменных было так `action:$action|type:$type|variation:$variation` (даже если одно из них принимает значения 0)
2. При отсутствии одной из трёх сохранялась концепция, например: `action:$action|variation:$variation`, `action:$action` и т.д.

UPD. Проблема именно с логическими выражениями. У меня не получается правильно задать последнее из-за `0`, `if` воспринимает его как bool(false) при выполнении. Но если я меняю условие в if, то он перестает реагировать на другой текст или ведет себя не корректно при отсутствии какого-то значения в `$variation`.

UPD2. Почему `$value_2` не подходит по условию? Была мысль что переменная принимает тип `boolean`, но при выводе через `var_dump` его тип `int`. Вопрос, почему так?

```
if ($value_1)
    var_dump($value_1); //string(11) "Hello World"

if ($value_2)
    var_dump($value_2); //Не подходит по условию...
else
    var_dump($value_2); //int(0)


if ($value_3)
    var_dump($value_3); //int(1)

if ($value_4)
    var_dump($value_4); //int(2)
```

Comment: А что это за цирк? Если не секрет... Условия дебажит надо раз не попадает куда надо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: @InDevX, эту строку я передаю на другой сервер, но так как не всегда сразу 3 значения передаются, а количество символов в строке ограничено, я решил таким образом сократить их. Так сказать, убрать не используемые.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не то. Тут именно проблема с if, не могу правильно указать сравнение для его корректного выполнения. Но за линк спасибо, пригодится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо пытаться писать ифы на все варианты ваших условий. Надо отфильтровать нужное, сложить в массив. А уже потом объединить результат через `|`.

```
$data = [];
if ($action) $data[] = "action:{$action}";
if ($type) $data[] = "type:{$type}";
if ($variation) $data[] = "variation:{$variation}";

$result = implode('|', $data);
```

для произвольного числа переменных, сложить их в массив как ключ-значение и отфильтровать

```
$data = ['action' => 1, 'type' => 2, 'variation' => 3];    
$filtered = array_filter($data, function($v){ return (bool) $v; });
$result = implode('|',  array_map(function($k, $v){ 
                 return "{$k}:{$v}";
             }, 
             array_keys($filtered), 
             $filtered
          ));
```

Условия соответственно можно поменять под ваши нужды, если нужны знания 0, например, но суть одна: не надо логику объединения результата пихать в ифы, еще и вложенные

Comment: В первом случае такая же проблема как и у меня, при любом значении переменной $variation отличного от 0, все работает ок. Но если $variation равен 0 то он его не определят =(

Comment: @Tymofii так проверьте не `if ($variation)` а `if (!is_null($variation))` например, или какое условие вам необходимо.

Comment: помогло , большое спасибо. Но мне все же интересно, почему `if ($variation)` при ` $variation = 0` не работает?

Comment: потому что 0 приводится к булевому false.

Answer (score 0):

Решение моей проблемы:
Создаю массив и делаю проверку по условиям. В конечном результате игнорируются не используемые значения. Так же отсутствует проблема с `0` при котором он воспринимался не как `int`, а как `bool`. Отдельноe спасибо **teran**.

```
$button = [
    "value" => $action ? "action:$action" : 'null'
];

if ($type) {
    $button["value"] .= "|type:$type";
}

if (!is_null($variation)) {
    $button["value"] .= "|variation:$variation";
}
```